# Github workflow not getting the requirements.txt file while building docker image

Tags: docker, github, aws-lambda, github-actions, requirements.txt

I have a github workflow that is building the docker image, installing dependencies using requirements.txt and pushing to AWS ECR. When I am checking it locally all is working fine but when github workflow is running it is not able to access the requirements.txt file and shows the following error

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Below is my simple dockerfile

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
CMD [ "api.handler" ]
```

Here is cicd yaml file.

```
name: Deploy to ECR

on:
  push:
    branches: [ metrics_handling ]

jobs:
  build:

    name: Build Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check Out Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ secrets.REGION }}

    - name: Build, Tag, and Push image to Amazon ECR
      id: tag
      run: |
        aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region}  | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com
        
        docker rmi --force ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest
        
        docker build --tag ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest -f API/Dockerfile . --no-cache
        
        docker push ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest
        
      
      env:
        accountid: ${{ secrets.ACCOUNTID}}
        region: ${{ secrets.REGION }}
        ecr_repository: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
```

Below is the structure of my directory. The requirements.txt file is inside API directory with all the related code that is needed to build and run the image.

[image]

Comment: Where is the requirements.txt file? Your screenshot does not show one.

Comment: @JohnHanley its inside API directory. The dockerfile and requirements.txt files both are in API directory.

Comment: You are specifying the Dockerfile in the API directory but you are building from the API's parent directory. That is why requirements.txt is not being found.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am using this build command in pipeline.yaml file.

docker build --tag ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest -f API/Dockerfile . --no-cache
 is this not enough?

Comment: @JohnHanley can you please suggest what changes I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file in your repo?

Comment: @frennky No. Dont have that

Comment: There are many ways to solve the requirements.txt problem, but I do not know how your container is designed. Should the API directory be the parent or a subdirectory?

Comment: @JohnHanley the API directory should be the parent one, everything inside API direcotry is important, other directories can be ignored.

Comment: Use this build command: **docker build --tag ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest API --no-cache**

Comment: @JohnHanley it worked. thankss!!! Can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the questions' comments, the Python **requirements.txt** file is located in the API directory. This command is is specifying the Dockerfile using a path in the API directory, but building the container in the current directory.

```
docker build --tag ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest -f API/Dockerfile . --no-cache
```

The correct approach is to build the container **in** the API directory:

```
docker build --tag ${accountid}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repository}:latest API --no-cache
```

Notice the change from **.** to **API** and removing the Dockerfile location **-f API/Dockerfile**